# SASL Authentication failed on Mongodb database

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, php-mongodb

I-m having an issue trying connect to Mongodb using PHP Mongodb driver.

Actually I have a database called LRS and it has a user called "juano" with a pwd:"12345" in my settings file I-m sure that I wrote the correct configuration.
But when I load my homepage in Laravel I receive this message:

```
MongoConnectionException (71)
HELP
Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: SASL Authentication failed on database'LRS': Authentication failed.
```

More specific the error found here

```
    if (isset($config['password']) && $config['password'])
    {
        $options['password'] = $config['password'];
    }

    return new MongoClient($dsn, $options);
}
```

And this is my config file

```
 <?php
   return [
     'connections' => [
       'mongodb' => [
         'driver'   => 'mongodb',
         'host'     => 'localhost',
         'port'     => 27017,
         'username' => 'juano',
         'password' => '12345',
         'database' => 'LRS'
      ],
  ]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I-m feel stupid because the problem was I started mongod in my local machine and then I ran my web into a Virtual Machine.
So, in my database connection config file I wrote "localhost" in the server field.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found a solution after reading your answer. Just for completness: 
In "/etc/mongod.conf", there should be: "net: bindIp: 0.0.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Please check

> .env

file in laravela

Add your all database configuration  details here and check it & and let me know if any issue after adding.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY= your key already given

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE= your database here
DB_USERNAME= your username here
DB_PASSWORD= your password here

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Since he doesn't reference env vars from his config setting them is irrelevant